# Google Play Game Services leaderboard -- what does it look like?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, leaderboard

Has anyone tried out the `Google Play Game Services leaderboard`?  I currently use `SwarmConnect` for my leaderboard but am not 100% satisfied with their UI and functionaility.

I have been searching since the Google I/O and have not been able to find an example.  Can someone provide a pic, video or link to what a finished leaderboard looks like?  I would love to see how it compares to `SwarmConnect`.

If this is not the place to post this, please advise on which Q/A website it should be placed on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I implemented the Google Play Games on my [Minesweeper 3D](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiirecords.minesweeper3d) game, these are the leaderboard and achievements screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I removed people's name and face to keep their privacy! In my opinion it is better and easier to use than Scoreloop and Openfeint (I already tested both).

Comment: Perfect answer!  And thank you for sharing some screenshots.  Cool 3D Minesweeper game too! :)

Comment: Is there a webpage to look at the leaderboard? Or can this only be displayed via the app/game?

Comment: As far as I know, it is only possible to see it through the app/game!